# Install error rb-appscript extconf.rb failed

Tags: ruby, rb-appscript

Fairly new to this so I've been trying to awhile to figure this out but unable to locate an answer.

```
gem update --system
```

When installing the rb-appscript I get the following error.

```
gem install rb-appscript
```

> Building native extensions. This could take a while...
>       ERROR:  Error installing rb-appscript:
>           ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
/Users/Dz/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150719-5167-en4sxa.rb extconf.rb
```

> extconf.rb failed
>   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
>   libraries and/or headers. Check the mkmf.log file for more details. You may
>   need configuration options.
>
> Provided configuration options:
>       --with-opt-dir
>       --without-opt-dir
>       --with-opt-include
>       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>       --with-opt-lib
>       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>       --with-make-prog
>       --without-make-prog
>       --srcdir=.
>       --curdir
>       --ruby=/Users/Dz/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
>   extconf.rb:44:in `': uninitialized constant Config (NameError)
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Dz/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rb-appscript-0.6.1 for inspection.
>   Results logged to /Users/Dz/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/rb-appscript-0.6.1/gem_make.out

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I found in another SO post that rb-appscript is no longer supported.  This is also printed in the header [across the homepage](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/rb-appscript/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for the headsup. I did see that as well.

Comment: This may be of use: https://rubygems.org/gems/rb-scpt/

Answer (score 1):

First, I hope you're enjoying Ruby. :-)

The `Config` module was renamed and deprecated to `RbConfig` around Ruby 1.9 (not sure when exactly). `Config` was removed entirely in Ruby 2, hence the `uninitialized constant Config` fatal error.

If you'd happened to be using 1.9.x instead of 2.2.2, you would have seen a deprecation warning, which probably would have tipped you off.

```
(localhost) ~ ruby -e "puts Config::CONFIG['RUBY_PROGRAM_VERSION']"
-e:1: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
1.9.3
(localhost) ~ ruby -e "puts RbConfig::CONFIG['RUBY_PROGRAM_VERSION']"
1.9.3
(localhost) ~ rbenv shell 2.2.3
(localhost) ~ ruby -e "puts Config::CONFIG['RUBY_PROGRAM_VERSION']"
-e:1:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Config (NameError)
(localhost) ~ ruby -e "puts RbConfig::CONFIG['RUBY_PROGRAM_VERSION']"
2.2.3
```

You could probably use Ruby 1.9 if you want to use `rb-appscript`, but I've never used that gem, so I can't speak to it specifically.

(You can easily install a version of 1.9 with `rbenv` and its `ruby-build` plugin.)

Answer (score -1):

Are you on OSX? Make sure you installed/upgraded the latest XCode from the AppStore.  Then run:

> gcc -v

If that fails, you may have to accept the xcode license by running:

> sudo gcc -v

and following the instructions.

Alternatively, you may install the XCode command line tools with:

> xcode-select --install

Then re-run:

> gem install *gem_nam*e